# Paint each graph trace the same color in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I have the following MATLAB code and I'm trying to make all of the plot traces black:

```
x = 20:0.01:30;
m1 = 25;
s1 = 2.5;
pdfNormal_1 = normpdf(x, m1, s1);
m2 = 25.478;
s2 = 0.1637;
pdfNormal_2 = normpdf(x, m2, s2);
m3 = 25.478;
s3 = 0.189;
pdfNormal_3 = normpdf(x, m3, s3);
set(gcf,'color','w');

g=findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
%set(g(1),'FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor','w')
%set(g(2),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
%set(g(3),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
set(gca,'Fontsize',12,'Fontname','euclid')
xlabel(' ') %título eixo xx
hold all;

%plot(x, pdfNormal_1, x, pdfNormal_2, x, pdfNormal_3);
%set(gcf,'Color',[0 0 0])
plot(x,pdfNormal_1,'-.')
plot(x,pdfNormal_2,':')
plot(x,pdfNormal_3,'-','LineWidth',2)
```

Can someone help me? I removed the `%` from `set(...);`, but it plots nothing.

Comment: you mean the red thicker one? or all the lines in black?

Comment: Do you want all of the lines to be painted black, or do you want the background to be black?

Comment: All the lines in black! I dont want any color! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite know what exactly you want.  You can either interpret this as:

1. You wanting all of your lines to be black
2. You wanting the background pane to be black.

Let's answer each question anyway so we have our bases covered.

## Wanting all lines black

For the third parameter in `plot`, you can use a single letter that specifies what colour you want for your lines within your plot.  Therefore, if you want all three of your plots black, use `k` after each invocation to `plot`.  `b` is actually reserved for blue.  Also, because you are calling `plot` more than once, each call to `plot` by default will overwrite the contents of the current figure with the latest invocation to `plot`, and so if you want all three plots to appear at the same time, you need to use `hold on`.  Therefore, place this at the end of your code:

```
hold on;
plot(x,pdfNormal_1,'k-.')
plot(x,pdfNormal_2,'k:')
plot(x,pdfNormal_3,'k-','LineWidth',2);
```

You can also get rid of any `set` commands as these aren't useful.  What you're actually doing is setting the **background of the figure** to white, which is probably not what you want to do.  By background, I mean the area where the axes appear, not the drawing area of the plot itself.

## Wanting the background pane black

If you want the background of where the plot appears to be black, it's a very simple one line statement.  You need to set **the current axes** colour, not the current figure.  Therefore, replace your `set(gcf...)` statement with `set(gca...)`.  Therefore:

```
set(gca,'Color',[0 0 0])
```

Now, if this is what you want, it'll be up to you to figure out what colours will appear on this plot nicely.  Red certainly appears nice here!

---

For more information about how `plot` works, check out the documentation page on MathWorks: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html.  It's actually very well explained!

Comment: Thanks mate! You ROCK! You made may day!! Regards :)